# Understanding step in derivation of convex conjugate

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, banach-spaces, duality-theorems

I'm reading the section on Fenchel's Duality Theorem in Barbu and Precupanu's *Convexity and Optimization in Banach Spaces*, and was reading the derivation of the dual problem for a special class of problems where the perturbations are generated by translations. The primal problem is defined as:
$$ \min\{f(x)-g(Ax); x\in X\}$$
where $X$ and $Y$ are real Banach spaces, $f: X\to ]-\infty, +\infty]$ is a proper, convex, and lower-semicontinuous function, $g: Y\to [-\infty, +\infty[$ is a proper, concave, and upper-semicontinuous function and $A:X\to Y$ is a linear continuous operator. They define the perturbation function $F:X\times Y \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ by $F(x,y)=f(x)-g(Ax-y)$. So far, so good. The only part of the derivation I am having issues following is from $(1)\to(2)$ when they begin to determine the conjugate of $F$:
$$ \begin{aligned}
F^*(x^*,y^*) &= \sup_{(x,y)\in X\times Y}\{(x,x^*)+(y,y^*)-f(x)+g(Ax-y)\}\quad (1)\\
&= \sup_{x\in X}\sup_{z\in Y}\{ (x,x^*)+(Ax,y^*)-f(x)+g(z)-(z,y^*)\} \quad (2)\\
\end{aligned}$$
I understand that $(1)$ is just the definition of convex conjugate, and the rest of the derivation after this point: they use properties of $\sup$ and $\inf$, the adjoint of $A$, and then definition of the convex conjugate to arrive at the final form. Sorry if this isn't the best question, but going from $(1)\to(2)$, how do they "split up" $g$ as they do, and where is $z$ coming from? It makes sense in context later in the derivation when they take the supremum over $z\in Y$ to then use the definition of the convex conjugate for $g$ to arrive at the final form. I suspect that I'm missing something painfully obvious. Any help showing how to get to $(2)$ from $(1)$ would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a substitution of variables, exchanging $y$ for $z = Ax - y$. Note that, for a fixed value $x$, the map $y \mapsto Ax - y$ is surjective, and hence
$$\sup_{z \in Y} \{(Ax - z, y^*) + g(z)\} = \sup_{y \in Y} \{ (y, y^*) + g(Ax - y)\}.$$
Then,
\begin{aligned}
F^*(x^*,y^*) &= \sup_{(x,y)\in X\times Y}\{(x,x^*)+(y,y^*)-f(x)+g(Ax-y)\} \\
&= \sup_{x\in X}\sup_{y\in Y}\{(x,x^*)+(y,y^*)-f(x)+g(Ax-y)\} \\
&= \sup_{x\in X}\sup_{z\in Y}\{ (x,x^*)+(Ax - z,y^*)-f(x)+g(z)\} \\
&= \sup_{x\in X}\sup_{z\in Y}\{ (x,x^*)+(Ax,y^*)-f(x)+g(z)-(z,y^*)\}.
\end{aligned}